# AWS Data Migration Service (SQL Server -> S3) keeps failing with "AlwaysOn BACKUP-ed data is not available"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm trying to use AWS Data Migration Service (DMS) (version 3.4.7) to move data from some SQL Server tables to S3.

When I run the migration from scratch, it works, but the ongoing replication always fails within a couple days, with an error message like this:

> Last Error AlwaysOn BACKUP-ed data is not available Task error
> notification received from subtask 0, thread 0
> [reptask/replicationtask.c:2883] [1020465] Error executing source
> loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component
> st_0_sqlbrewer-aw; Stream component 'st_0_sqlbrewer-aw' terminated
> [reptask/replicationtask.c:2891] [1020465] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR
> Error Level FATAL

Upon investigation, it seems that the issue might be that it is looking for backups more than 7 days back, and we delete our backups after 7 days.

But I need a way for this to work without keeping all backups indefinitely.

Hoping someone has some helpful tips.

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but backup rotation typically requires doing a full backup prior to rotation, otherwise you're only backing up data that's been written in the last X amount of time. Ongoing replication doesn't function this way.

Comment: There is an AWS forum post with some clues:
https://repost.aws/questions/QUji7kwy_YQCqZesfRkvcEUw/how-to-resolve-dms-failure-to-access-lsn-issue
It implies that our backup retention period (7 days) is too short. 
However, it doesn't provide a solution.